# Using listview and adding the data for next class

Tags: java, android-studio

So, i've been trying to develop an app where u order sandwiches by yourself. So far I've managed everything with the listview, what type of sandwiches you can order etc.

But im unsure on the next step which is when someone clicks a certain item the item must be saved somehow. My guess in an Arraylist?

So thats what I need help for, somehow record the click so the user can see which items they clicked and confirm the purchase on the next screen(Which will be the next class).

I saw this youtube video, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VBN3LMb7rss&t=166s thats how I want to "store" the "data", or something similar.

Kind regards,
Here's my code.

```
 package com.example.boo.cafestudent;

 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.AdapterView;
 import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
 import android.widget.ListAdapter;
 import android.widget.ListView;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 import java.util.ArrayList;

 public class Order extends AppCompatActivity {

//ListView mackorListView;
//ArrayList <string> order_item_name;
// public final ArrayList<String> bestallning = new ArrayList<>();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.orderactivity);

    String[] mackor ={"Ostsmörgås","Skinksmörgås","Ost och Skinksmörgås",      "Salamismörgås","Räksmörgås",
 "Rensmörgås", "Älgsmörgås", "Köttbullesmörgås"};



 ListAdapter johansadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mackor);

    //hämtar ListView
 ListView mackorListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListViewMackor);

//Hämtar data från array stringen

   // final String[] array_mackor =     getResources().getStringArray(R.array.arraymackor);

    //skapandet av en array adapter

    //Själva adaptern till ListView
    mackorListView.setAdapter(johansadapter);


    //kopplar onClicklistener till Listvie
    mackorListView.setOnItemClickListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,     int position, long id){
                    String mackor = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
                    Toast.makeText(Order.this, mackor + " har lagts      till", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }
    );
}



public void onClick (View View){
    Intent i = new Intent (getApplicationContext(), Confirmation.class);
    //Intent.putExtra("bestallning",bestallning);
    startActivity(i);
 }}
```

Comment: One way is to store the items in a database. Google provides the Room API to help you interact with a database.

Comment: I saw this youtube video, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VBN3LMb7rss&t=166s thats how I want to "store" the "data", or something similar.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to allow the user to select items from the list? And then what will you do with the items?

Comment: Correct, then the user will move onto the next activity seeing what they picked and then confirm the order.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add the item clicked into an Arraylist everytime it gets clicked. Declare an arraylist at the top as an instance variable. The code could look like this.  If you want to access the values of the array in another activity or class use putExtra () or declare the arraylist public static.

```
 ArrayList<String> clickedSandwiches = new ArrayList<String>();



   mackorListView.setOnItemClickListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,     int position, long id){
                    String mackor = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
                    Toast.makeText(Order.this, mackor + " har lagts      till", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    clickedSandwiches.add(mackor);

                }
            }
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you! A generel question, when trying to move onto the next activity using intent and a new window doesnt pop up, does it often depend on the current activity intenting from, or the one ur trying to get to?

Comment: It's hard to tell without actually seeing the code, consider asking that in a new question. If my answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted :)